# Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{F}_3[\mathbb{Z}/3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{F}_3[\mathbb{Z}/3]$.

$R$ is not semi-simple since $|\mathbb{Z}/3|=3=0\in\mathbb{F}_3$ by the converse of Maschke's theorem.

I am confused how to find a surjective ring homomorphism $\phi$ in general with a semi-simple target so I can say $J(R)=ker \phi$

I have an example for $F_3[S_3]$: [image]

But I cannot use this homomorphism for my example. Also, could someone confirm that the Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{R}[S_3]$ is $0$ since the ring is semi-simple by Maschke's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The augmentation map that sends $\sum r_gg\mapsto \sum r_g$ has kernel generated by elements of the form $1-g$ for $g$ in the group. All of these are nilpotent, so the augmentation ideal is nilpotent in this case.  The quotient is a field, so in fact you have found the Jacobson radical, which in this case is the unique maximal ideal.

Comment: I have never heard of that map - after googling it looks it is the map from the group ring $F_3[Z_3]$ in our case to $F_3$. $r_g(g-1)$ so I agree with your kernel. Why are they nilpotent? So the quotient $F_3[Z_3]/(1-g)$ is a field? I'm not sure what theorem you are using. Is it : Surjective ring homomorphism, semi-simple target $F_3$, kernel nilpotent ideal?

Comment: @Walter it's a very important ideal and map!  It's nilpotent because of the Freshman Dream Theorem: $(1-g)^p=1^p-g^p=1-1=0$.  Then an ideal of a commutative ring generated by nilpotent elements is nil. I think you and I are in agreement in your last sentence of your last comment.

Comment: Can I write $J(R)=\langle 1-g \rangle$ where $g \in \mathbb{Z}/3$ to finish? Or is that wrong/bad notation

Comment: @Walter I think you mean $\langle\{1-g\mid g\in G\}\rangle$.